# Loop doesn't render anything

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a array named *enableDisabled*. This have array os elements, has an id and a value of check.

HTML

```
 <li *ngFor="let alarm of enableDisabled">
      <div class="styleCheckbox">
           <div class='form-check'><label><input type='checkbox' value="{{alarm.id}}"
                [checked]="alarm.check" name="alarm{{alarm.id}}"><span class='label-text'></span></label>{{'AlertMeter'+alarm.id | translate}}
           </div>
      </div>
 </li>
```

ARRAY

```
0: {id: 602, check: true}
1: {id: 603, check: true}
2: {id: 604, check: true}
3: {id: 605, check: true}
4: {id: 607, check: true}
5: {id: 608, check: true}
6: {id: 609, check: true}
7: {id: 610, check: true}
8: {id: 612, check: true}
9: {id: 613, check: true}
10: {id: 614, check: true}
11: {id: 615, check: true}
12: {id: 616, check: true}
13: {id: 617, check: true}
14: {id: 765, check: true}
15: {id: 120, check: true}
16: {id: 121, check: true}
17: {id: 122, check: true}
18: {id: 125, check: true}
19: {id: 126, check: true}
20: {id: 127, check: true}
21: {id: 128, check: true}
22: {id: 129, check: true}
23: {id: 130, check: true}
24: {id: 131, check: true}
25: {id: 132, check: true}
26: {id: 133, check: true}
27: {id: 134, check: true}
28: {id: 135, check: true}
```

So, the question is: The for doesn't work and doesn't render anything, it seems that array has incorrect format or something like that. Anybody can explain me what's wrong?

Comment: Is there an `*ngIf` in the parents of the `li` preventing the list from being displayed?

Comment: What's the error in the console?

Comment: No errors in console, no *ngIf in the HTML.

Comment: Where are you setting value to `enableDisabled` ? you can try printing `enableDisabled` in the template before *ngFor `{{enableDisabled | json}}` to check if data is available in the template.

Comment: I think its working, PS. I have removed translate.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14svnz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: My fault, i declared as local variable in a function so *ngFor can´t get it.